# Firefox Website Bug in Contact Form

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

There is a bug happening in the contact form of a site I am making only in Firefox.

It looks perfectly fine in all browsers except for firefox. If anyone can see what the bug is, that'd be great.

jeremybreit.com/pgr

Comment: A picture of your site isn't your site and doesn't help. People will need to see html, javascript, and maybe css in order to help you out. Post code in your question and/or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some css rules are in collision... and hr is floated - this will fix it:

```
form {
    margin: 0px 0px 1rem;
    clear: both;
}
```